# fgets inside while loop for login validation

Tags: c

I have this login program in c which gives the user up to 3 attempts to login.
I am using fgets to avoid buffer overflow but when i type more than 16 characters this happens:

> Enterlogin:aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
>   Enter password:Enter login:Enter password:Enter login:Enter
>   password:Invalid login and/or password

Instead of reading only the first 16 'a'.
Here is my code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int checkpasswd();

int main() {

    int result;

    result = checkpasswd();

    if (result == 1)
        printf("Password correct - Login approved\n");
    else
        printf("Invalid login and/or password\n");

    return 0;
}

int checkpasswd(void) {

    char name[16], passwd[16];
    int correct = 0, attempts = 0;

    while ((attempts != 3)&&(correct == 0)) {
        printf("Enter login:");
        fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);
        printf("Enter password:");
        fgets(passwd, sizeof(passwd), stdin);

        if ((strncmp(name, "admin", strlen(name) - 1) == 0) && (strncmp(passwd, "secret", strlen(passwd) - 1) == 0))
            correct = 1;
        else
            attempts++;
    }

    if (correct)
        return 1;
    else return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To begin with you should check what [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) returns. If it fails it will return `NULL`.

As for your problem, the [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) function will not necessarily read a whole line. If you tell [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) to read at most `16` characters (including terminator) then [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) will read up to 15 character from the input, and then leave the rest in the buffer. It will *not* read up until newline and discard what doesn't fit in the buffer.

To validate that you get a whole line with `fgets`, check that the last character in the string is a newline.

---

To help you along the way, you need to do something like

```
if (fgets(name, sizeof name, stdin) == NULL)
{
    // Error or end-of-file, either way no use in continuing
    break;
}

if (strcspn(name, "\n") == strlen(name))
{
    // No newline in string, there might be more to read in the input buffer
    // Lets read and discard all remaining input in the input buffer until a newline
    int c;
    while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && c != '\n')
    {
    }

    // TODO: Should probably tell the user about this event

    // Continue with next attempt
    ++attempts;
    continue;
}
```

I do recommend that you break this out into a separate function that you can reuse for reading of the password as well.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the code in the question I think it works. Check it out if you like.

Comment: In OP's case `if (strcspn(name, "\n") == strlen(name))` cloud be replaced with  a more efficient `if (strchr(name, '\n') == NULL)`

Comment: @chux True, but then perhaps even use `strrchr` since the "normal" and hopefully most common case would be valid input.